# Identify string contents, and verify

Tags: c#

I'm still fairly new to C#,

I'm making a 'mini-username checker' if you will

so far, the username is 2 numbers, followed by a name,

example

```
13Samuel
```

which can also be typed as

```
13samuel
```

What I am trying to do is detect if the first two characters makes a number between 0 and 99 then detect if the third character is a letter (a-z) lowercase or caps.

Thank you for reading,

Samuel

Comment: What have you tried already? There are plenty of similar questions. Just search a bit. Little hint: search for pattern matching using regular expressions.

Comment: You could take different approaches, regular expressions, manually checking the first three characters of the string... They have different advantages and disadvantages. I would encourage you trying something and comming back if you get some problems we could help you with. In my opinion I would go regular expressions (in c# Regex)

Comment: a string is internally represented as a `char[]` so it would be possible for you to iterate through it using a for-loop. [Char.IsDigit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a method then can be helpfull here. If the third position is a digit, then you have clearly overstepped your limit of `99`.... as for the rest have a look at [Char.IsLetter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check first two letters are in between **0 to 99** and followed by character then you can try followings

```
    string name = "13Samuel";

    if(name.Length > 2)
    {
        int number;
        if(Int32.TryParse(name.Substring(0,2), out number)){
            Console.WriteLine(number > 0 && number < 99 & Char.IsLetter(name[2]) ? "Success" : "Failed");
        }

    }
```

POC: .[Net Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w3qm5V)

Answer (score 3):

There's certainly a regex approach but with string methods and LINQ it's imo easier to read:

```
string name = "13Samuel";
bool valid = name.Length > 2 && name.Remove(2).All(char.IsDigit) && char.IsLetter(name[2]);
```

or maybe you don't want to allow all letters but just a-z and A-Z:

```
// store this in a field so that it doesn't always need to be generated 
char[] allowed = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".SelectMany(c => new[]{c, char.ToLower(c)}).ToArray(); 

bool valid = name.Length > 2 && name.Remove(2).All(char.IsDigit) && allowed.Contains(name[2]);
```

Comment: Why not using `HashSet<T>` for `allowed` ?

Comment: @Fabjan: because i didn't want to confuse with a new type and it's not necessary to solve the task. Furthermore, a `HashSet` is only more efficient if the hashcode can be determined fast(which is the case in `char.GetHashCode`) and if it's large. With 48 letters i doubt that `HashSet.Contains` is faster than with an array.

Answer (score 1):

I was editing a previous post but it was removed.

You can use regex to match strings to formats

For example :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]+");
    Match match = regex.Match(username);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        //it is valid
    }
```

for this regex "[\d]{2}" means 2 digits and [a-zA-Z]+ is any number of letters from the alphabet.

You can check the documentation for more info on how to use regex in C#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

the following methods returns whether your string is valid:

```
public static bool validateString(string stringToValidate) {
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]+$");
        return rgx.Match(stringToValidate).Success;
    }
```

explanation:

^ - marks the beginning of your string

\d - matches all digits from 0-9

{1,2} - digits may occur 1-2 times

[a-zA-Z] - matches all literals from a-z and from A-Z

+ - matches the literals 1 or multiple times

you can check the documentation for further information about Regular Expresssions in C#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: This should make a comment instead an answer, it help the user but does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There  you go:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    static bool Answer(string stringToTest)
    {
        var classifier = @"^\d\d[a-zA-Z]";
        Regex regex = new Regex(classifier);
        return regex.Match(stringToTest).Success;
    }
```

So remember to use regex
and you could use https://regex101.com/ to test your classifiers